# How different between "form" and "form_widget" in Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have read [Twig Template Form Function and Variable Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html) on the Symfony website. However, I don't quite understand the main different between them.

For example,

`{{ form(form)}}` and `{{ form_widget(form) }}`

So, my questions are:

How different between two of these, do they generate different `HTML` code? and when is one preferred over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`form(form)` will generate the HTML for the form label, the form input, and also the form errors for all of the form elements.

`form_widget(form.x)` will only generate the HTML for the form input(ex. textbox), so you would have to generate the others yourself, or also include `form_label(form.x)` and `form_error(form.x)`

Answer (score 1):

`{{ form(form)}}` is generate whole form with `<form></form>` tags and them fields at once. `{{ form_widget(form) }}` is used for generate specific field separately. Also read the docs about [Symfony forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) and [Rendering each Field by Hand](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand)